# Add a number of '=' in a rest (reStructuredText) document that equals to characters from last line?

Tags: vim, restructuredtext

I want to use a shortcut to add needed `=` (from Section/Title [reStructuredText syntax](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickref.html#contents)) according to the last line.

So, suppose (being | the cursor position)

```
Title
|
```

and pressing an specific mapping mapped to a function, add a number of `=` that equals to the last line (where `Title` is), becoming:

```
Title
=====|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sequence will get you close:

```
kyyp:.s/./=/g
```

Duplicate the previous line, then in that line, change every character to an equals sign.  Map that to a key sequence you like, and try it out.

Comment: You can also use the replace command : `kyypv$r=` Copy a line, select it until the end, then replace selected characters by =

Comment: @Xavier T. - Your answer looks more elegant. And adding $ to the end of your solution does exactly what I want with my cursor. This should be an answer and not a comment IMO. Thanks!

Comment: I would need to call :nohlsearch after your solution, but it works as well. Thanks for answering!

Comment: @Xavier T.: You can shorten that a bit by using `V` instead of `v$`.  With the added `$` to move the cursor: `kyypVr=$`

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
:execute "normal " . strlen(getline(line(".") - 1)) . "i="
```

`strlen(getline(line(".") - 1))` returns the lenght of the line above the current position. The result is that the command `Ni=` is executed, inserting `=` N times.

Answer (score 1):

For a mapping I would have used:

```
put=repeat('=', col('$')-1)
```

For something more interactive, I would have use the same solution as Ned's.

(I don't like my mappings to change the various registers like `@"` or `@/`)

Answer (score 1):

My `vim-rst-sections` vim plugin will convert lines to section headings:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4486

In your case, you'd put the cursor on the line, and type `<leader><leader>d` to get a top-level heading like this:

```
#####
Title
#####
```

A few repeats of `<leader><leader>d` will take you down to the standard hierarchy of Python ReST sections to the `=`.